# calling a mapFragment in an activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, dictionary, fragment

I want to use a **mapfragment** in my **activity** so I created the map's xml file and the java file and I call it in my **main activit**y but I am getting this error

**java.lang.StackOverflowError** 
on   this line

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
```

> 06-29 11:14:26.264 23599-23599/com.sifast.appsocle E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        java.lang.StackOverflowError
>                                                                            at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java:201)
>                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1022)
>                                                                            at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2131)
>                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:865)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
>                                                                            at com.sifast.appsocle.mapFrag.onCreateView(mapFrag.java:69)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>                                                                            at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:168)
>                                                                            at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>                                                                            at com.sifast.appsocle.mapFrag.onCreateView(mapFrag.java:69)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>                                                                            at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:168)
>                                                                            at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>                                                                            at com.sifast.appsocle.mapFrag.onCreateView(mapFrag.java:69)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>                                                                            at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:168)
>                                                                            at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>                                                                            at com.sifast.appsocle.mapFrag.onCreateView(mapFrag.java:69)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1036)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1230)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1332)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2288)
>                                                                            at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>                                                                            at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:168)
>                                                                            at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
>                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>                                                                            at com.sifast.appsocle.mapFrag.onCreateView(mapFrag.java:69)
>                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java

Here is my xml and java

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-au
to"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.sifast.appsocle.mapFrag"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.sifast.appsocle.mapFrag"
/>
```

java code

```
public class mapFrag  extends  android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {


public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private GoogleMap map;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private boolean isGPSEnabled, isNetworkEnabled, isGPSTrackingEnabled;
private String provider_info;
private static String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getName();
private Location location;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
// The minimum distance to change updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute


public mapFrag() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    getMyLocation();
    return view;

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    //txtOutput.setText(location.toString());
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));


    try {

        map.clear();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    LatLng mypos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    //camera annimation
    CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(mypos)
            .zoom(70)
            .bearing(45)
            .tilt(65)
            .build();

    CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);

 map.animateCamera(camUpd3);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mypos).title("here i am !!"));

    // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mypos));
    //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mypos));


}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map= googleMap;


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);


    return;

}

void getMyLocation(){


    // definition of the location manager

    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //definition of the listenner
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // setting the camera of the map to positionate the marker in the current position
            LatLng myLaLn = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myLaLn)
                    .zoom(15)
                    .bearing(45)
                    .tilt(70)
                    .build();

            CameraUpdate camUpd3 = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);

            map.animateCamera(camUpd3);

            //  setting the marker in the current position

            Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                    .title("My position")
                    .snippet("Population: 776733"));


        }


    };
}}
```

and this is how I  call it in the on create function

```
     mapFrag myMap = new mapFrag();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.myHomeContainer,myMap,"test");

        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: you have not posted the xml file

Comment: this is my xml file 

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-au
    to"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.sifast.appsocle.mapFrag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sifast.appsocle.mapFrag"
   />

Comment: is this xml file named as "fragment_map" ?

Comment: yes it is named fragment_map

Comment: please update your post with xml file and logcat

Comment: Error `FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.StackOverflowError` is usually encountered due to infinity loop.

Please check this [post](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/440) in GitHub for more information on what causes that error. And in addition to that, the concept given in this similar SO post - [Getting FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.StackOverflowError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620974/getting-fatal-exception-main-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-when-creating-an-obje) might also help.